# How to add literals to panels in codebehind, in order to create a dashboard-like layout grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, highcharts

Currently this is working:

```
<div id="DashboardDiv" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlA" runat="server" CssClass="Widget" Width ="900">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlB" runat="server" CssClass="Widget" Width ="900">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

I need to use a literal, in order to use dotNet Highcharts in codebehind.

The problem however, is that I'm creating a Dashboard which will display multiple widgets. Right now my testcase consists of 1 widget, but I want to eventually expand that to an indetermined number of widgets.

I feel that I need to create panels (and literals added to these), based on the amount of widgets a user wants, on run-time. How do I do this?

I tried something like this:

```
protected static List<Panel> panelList = new List<Panel>();

Panel myChildPanel = new Panel();
myChildPanel.Width = 900;
panelList.Add(myChildPanel);
DashboardDiv.Controls.Add(myChildPanel);
```

And then adding the literal to this List of Panels, to a specified panel:

```
Literal ltrChart = new Literal();
ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
panelList[counter].Controls.Add(ltrChart);
```

This feels like an ugly way of doing things. 
**Basically I'm looking for this:**

How can I create panels/areas/zones that are capable of containing a Literal, in code-behind, so that I can create a dashboard filled with widgets-look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using asp placeholders? I believe they will help you acheive what you want to do. They allow you to place and kind of controls in them and you can hide and show a placeholder based on a specific condition. For example

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" visible="<%=CMSContext.CurrentUserIsAuthenticated()%> >
<div class="faq-listing itmList faq odd">
<h2 class="heading"> Home</h2>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSubFaq" runat="server">
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</asp:Placeholder>
```

Comment: I will look into this possibility. But from the looks of it, wouldn't I be pre-defining how many placeholders I'd want? Because that's the problem, I don't know how many places I want to hold, it depends on the input of the user on runtime.


For example, if I pre-define 6 placeholders for widgets, and a user creates 8 widgets, won't I miss 2 placeholder controls in this scenario?

Comment: After reading about the placeholder control, I realize you can dynamically add several controls to one placeholder. I think you're right, this sounds perfect for what I need! Thanks a lot!